# Fill a cells value based sequence every new row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sequence, vlookup, repeat, flatten

Is it possible that each time a new row is added, the value of a cell is automatically filled based on a sequence that repeats indefinitely?

What I need to do is fill in the Sales Rep name in a column (there are only 6 sales reps in the list) every time a new cell is added.

Here is the spreadsheet I'm working with (the expected result is on "Leads Desired Outcome" and the formula I tried is on "Failed test".

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wvA7t7-S5agwDNEy_N5eIe58YPT1-9vZY8uWwB4sUZQ/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: its possible. share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Use arrayformula as the header of column with the appropriate formula

Comment: Thanks @player0, this is the spreadsheet with an example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wvA7t7-S5agwDNEy_N5eIe58YPT1-9vZY8uWwB4sUZQ/edit?usp=sharing

I need to fill the column "Sales Rep" of the sheet "Leads without Sales Rep" with the name of a sales rep, based on a sequence of 6 people automatically when adding a new row.

I tried something, on the sheet called "Failed test". The extra column "SalesCount" doesn't work because I don't know how to automate the value of that column every time a new row is added, which is why I'm stuck. 

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in E1:

```
={"Sales Rep"; INDEX(VLOOKUP(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(FLATTEN(
 SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(ROWS(A:A)/MAX('Sales Reps'!A:A)), MAX('Sales Reps'!A:A))-(
 SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(ROWS(A:A)/MAX('Sales Reps'!A:A)), 1, 0)*MAX('Sales Reps'!A:A))), 
 ROWS(A:A)-1, 1), 'Sales Reps'!A:B, 2, 0))}
```

[image]